# String with special character is not displaying into email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, special-characters, email-templates

I have string like : `'<New guest with special chars>'`

Its displaying nice with rails view helper:

```
h '<New guest with special chars>' => '<New guest with special chars>'
```

but when I am sending this string to email then its not displaying and seems in firebug like :

`'<new chars="" special="" with="" guest=""></new>'`

because email treating it as html tag . Anyone has any idea, how to display it properly ?

Any ideas & suggestions would be very welcome .

Comment: what is the format of file which is being sent ? .txt.erb ?

Comment: Preparing html view in .rb file and sending message into the '.html.erb' .
ActionEmailer will use this file to send message .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am able to get the string as desired . I using function to convert my string to escaped one .

```
CGI::escapeHTML(MY_STRING)
```

Answer (score 1):

What Content-Type and Content-Disposition are you using to send the e-mail? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

If you sent an HTML e-mail, you need to encode your text correctly so that you use &gt instead of > etc.  http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html